# Prove that $(a\lor b)\land a\equiv a$ without using truth tables

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, proof-theory

Please help me solve $(a\lor b)\land a\equiv a$ without using a truth table. Meaning that if there exists a choice between two things ($a$ or $b$) and one of them had to be chosen ($a$) then that is the same as simply $a$.

Comment: Since truth tables are out, which methods of proof _do_ you have available? Algebraic rules? Natural deduction? Hilbert axioms and modus ponens?

Comment: I do not have any specifications, as long as I manage to prove it. I have been trying to play around with negations and de Morgan's but I feel I am out of my depth here.

Comment: See [Absorption Laws](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Absorption_Laws_(Logic)/Conjunction_Absorbs_Disjunction/Proof_2).

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, managed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
(a\vee b)\wedge a\equiv (a\vee b)\wedge (a\vee F)\equiv a\vee(b\wedge F)\equiv a\vee F\equiv a
$

Answer (score 2):

If you had to solve this using boolean algebra, then this would normally simply be one of the equivalence principles:

**Absorption**

$P \land (P \lor Q) = P$

$P \lor (P \land Q) = P$

... but since that would make the problem trivial, I assume you are not asked to do this using boolean algebra.

So, what's left? Maybe a formal proof? Many proof systems exist, with different sets of rules, so unless you tell us that you need to do a formal proof, an wat rules you have, I'll skip this method as well.

Instead, I'll just do a non-formal proof based on the semantics of the operators involved:

If $(a \lor b) \land a$ is true then both $a \lor b$ and $a$ are true, from whch it immediately follows that $a$ is true. So, $(a \lor b) \land a$ implies $a$ is true.

If $a$ is true, then $a \lor b$ will be true as well, since at least one of $a$ and $b$ is true. So, both $a$ and $a \lor b$ is true, and therefore $(a \lor b) \land a$ is true. So, $a$ implies $(a \lor ) \land a$.

Since the two statements imply each other, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to prove that $a$ implies $(a\lor b)\land a$ and that $(a\lor b)\land a$ implies $a$. This means that they imply each other and are equivalent logically.